# How to do a subquery in Linq

Tags: linq, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have the classes `Foo` and `Bar`:

```
public class Foo
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public IEnumerable<Bar> Bars {get;private set;}
}

public class Bar
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Type {get;set;}
  public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

These two classes map to tables in the database in a predictable '`Bar` has  foreign key to `Foo`' kind of way. (I can provide the FluentNHibernate mappings if required).

I would like to write a linq query that does the equivalent of this:

```
SELECT FOOS.*, (SELECT Description FROM BARS WHERE BAR.FOOID = FOO.ID AND BAR.TYPE = 'Irish')
FROM FOOS
WHERE FOO.ID = 1
```

How would I do this?

And yes, I'm aware that the query will break if the `Foo` has more than one Irish `Bar` (although I could use `TOP 1` type syntax to protect it). And yes, I mean to use a subquery rather than a join.

**EDIT:**

This is what I'm trying so far:

```
var foosWithIrishBarDescription = FooRepository.All.Where(x => x.Id == 1).Select(x=> new {FooId = x.Id, IrishBarDescription = x.Bars.Where(y => y.Type == "Irish").Select(y => y.Description)});
```

But I get the error 'The method 'Select' is not implemented.' Can this not be achieved in Linq to NHibernate? (I'm using 2.1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your IEnumerable is actually a property called "Bars":

```
var foos = dbContext.FOOS.Where(f => f.ID == 1);
var foobar = foos.Select(f => new {f, f.Bars.FirstOrDefault(b => b.TYPE == "Irish")});
```

Comment: This would result in two SELECTs to the database wouldn't it?

Comment: It would not. (because of deferred execution).

Comment: Thank you for pointing out I hadn't named the collection! I have corrected that now. I will check out your way of doing it now.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know you could split the Linq expressions like that. I don't know whether to mark this as the answer or not. From a Linq point of view, it's correct. However, from an NHibernate point of view, it's not correct because NHibernate doesn't support it. Bollocks, I'll give it to you.

Comment: Whoops, I didn't see the NHibernate bit.  It was early.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
from f in dbContext.FOOSs
where f.ID = 1
select new
{
    FOOS = f,
    Description = (from b in dbContext.BARSs 
                   where b.FOOID == f.ID && b.TYPE == "Irish" 
                   select b.Description).FirstOrDefault(),
}
```

If you only have one `BAR` for each `FOO` you can also express the query as a join.

If you have a FK relation between `FOO` and `BAR` you can use that information to get a more readable query

```
from f in dbContext.FOOSs
where f.ID = 1
select new
{
    FOOS = f,
    Description = (from b in f.BARSs 
                   where b.TYPE == "Irish" 
                   select b.Description).FirstOrDefault(),
}
```

Comment: There is an association between the classes Foo and Bar so my Linq query needs to use the association. For example, Description = from b in f.Bars .......)